# Invalid value for field exception while deserializing object using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I have a `List` of Non-Generic type which i want to store in `SharedPreferences`. For this, I am using **Gson** to convert the `List` to String and then storing it to `SharedPreferences` like this :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type fooType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserFeedMaster>>() {}.getType();
// feedTempList is the ArrayList of type UserFeedMaster class
String gsonFeeds = gson.toJson(feedTempList,fooType);
prefs.edit().putString("recent_feedlist", gsonFeeds).commit();
```

And later on I am trying to get back the values as `ArrayList<UserFeedMaster>` in this way :

```
String gsonFeed = prefs.getString("recent_feedlist", null);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserFeedMaster>>(){}.getType();
List<UserFeedMaster> historyFeeds = gson.fromJson(gsonFeed,type);
```

For Serializing the data, it is working fine. But the problem here is when I am De-serializing it, I get error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field`  at line `List<UserFeedMaster> historyFeeds = gson.fromJson(gsonFeed,type);`

**Error Log :**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
at java.lang.reflect.Field.setField(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:588)
at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setFieldValue(FieldInfo.java:245)
at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setValue(FieldInfo.java:206)
at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:103)
at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:47)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
at com.myapp.sample.RecentFeedsFragment.onActivityCreated(RecentFeedsFragment.java:178)`
```

**UserFeedMaster.java**

```
 public class UserFeedMaster {

    @Id
    private String feedBlobKey;
    private Date feedDateTime;
    private int feedLikes;
    private boolean feedIsPrivate;
    private boolean userIsAnonymous;
    private String feedTags;
    private boolean isFeedDeleted;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getFeedBlobKey() {
        return feedBlobKey;
    }

    public void setFeedBlobKey(String feedBlobKey) {
        this.feedBlobKey = feedBlobKey;
    }

    public Date getFeedDateTime() {
        return feedDateTime;
    }

    public void setFeedDateTime(Date feedDateTime) {
        this.feedDateTime = feedDateTime;
    }


    public int getFeedLikes() {
        return feedLikes;
    }

    public void setFeedLikes(int feedLikes) {
        this.feedLikes = feedLikes;
    }

    public boolean isFeedIsPrivate() {
        return feedIsPrivate;
    }

    public void setFeedIsPrivate(boolean feedIsPrivate) {
        this.feedIsPrivate = feedIsPrivate;
    }

    public boolean isUserIsAnonymous() {
        return userIsAnonymous;
    }

    public void setUserIsAnonymous(boolean userIsAnonymous) {
        this.userIsAnonymous = userIsAnonymous;
    }

    public String getFeedTags() {
        return feedTags;
    }

    public void setFeedTags(String feedTags) {
        this.feedTags = feedTags;
    }

    public boolean isFeedDeleted() {
        return isFeedDeleted;
    }

    public void setFeedDeleted(boolean isFeedDeleted) {
        this.isFeedDeleted = isFeedDeleted;
    }

}
```

**JSON response :**

```
[
    {
        "feedBlobKey": "AMIfv944GCtKglU0zOhVTq6F0dG9Aj1LxtIN5Qz0d3CuaRWO3MWIXd_1eCBxVJA_T6FNjx83hq-ORmnAoivTz2IxL120iQYtePBUPoTru6sxKj5iLZmkRxqaIodwEgknUQPvrkEG_37rlUIoycRHUwnPJlmc_6lmtN32tw9-b5NW60wP7u5AHZY",
        "feedDateTime": {
            "value": 1396953609433,
            "tzShift": 0,
            "dateOnly": false
        },
        "feedDeleted": false,
        "feedIsPrivate": false,
        "feedLikes": 0,
        "kind": "userfeedmasterendpoint#resourcesItem"
    },
    {
        "feedBlobKey": "AMIfv944GCtKglU0zOhVTq6F0dG9Aj1LxtIN5Qz0d3CuaRWO3MWIXd_1eCBxVJA_T6FNjx83hq-ORmnAoivTz2IxL120iQYtePBUPoTru6sxKj5iLZmkRxqaIodwEgknUQPvrkEG_37rlUIoycRHUwnPJlmc_6lmtN32tw9-b5NW60wP7u5AHZY",
        "feedDateTime": {
            "value": 1396953609433,
            "tzShift": 0,
            "dateOnly": false
        },
        "feedDeleted": false,
        "feedIsPrivate": false,
        "feedLikes": 0,
        "kind": "userfeedmasterendpoint#resourcesItem"
    }
]
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Please help me on why I am getting this error and how can I resolve it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Ideally, post a small reproducible example, with your classes and JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure.Please wait a while.

Comment: RecentFeedsFragment.java, Line number 178 ??

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto `List<UserFeedMaster> historyFeeds = gson.fromJson(gsonFeed,type);`

Comment: I have a feeling , you need to debug the type and gsonfeed before passing these to fromJson function, check if it's having data or null value ??

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've posted my class and error logs here.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I've debug it and it is having data.

Comment: If both are correct values, then it must work.

Comment: I don't get the same exception at all when deserializing the JSON you posted.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto yes,but i am getting this error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Then what can be the reason in my case ?

Comment: You're not showing us what you're really doing. Also a `Date` object cannot be deserialized from your `feedDateTime` JSON field unless you've setup your `Gson` in a way you haven't shown us. Or maybe `Date` isn't `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `feedDateTime` has `DateTime` value

Comment: Look, you have to fix something. The errors you are reporting don't match the JSON or POJO you've posted. And you say `feedDateTime` is a `DateTime` when it appears as a `Date` in your code. What is right? What is wrong? Please clarify _everything_.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using GoogleAppEngine, and my class is an entity. In my db, `feedDateTime` is of type `DateTime` and here i am using object of type `java.util.Date`

Comment: why your JSON response has "kind": "xxxxx", but class UserFeedMaster has no field "kind" ?

Comment: @HenryChuang that is returned by default with response, but not member of class

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON has this:

```
"feedDateTime": {
    "value": 1396953609433,
    "tzShift": 0,
    "dateOnly": false
}
```

Your Java class has this:

```
private Date feedDateTime;
```

Which one of these is not like the other? That is what is producing the error.

GSON isn't going to magically convert that JSON into a `Date` object. You either need to create a Java class (`FeedDateTime`) that matches that JSON object or write a custom deserializer for your `UserFeedMaster` class.